# Rails 4 & JQuery UI datepicker - icon not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using the date picker widget from JQuery UI in my Rails 4 app. The date picker is working as expected except that the calendar image is not showing up.

I guess my questions are...

1. What is the proper directory to store the 'calendar.png' file that will be used in buttonImage?
2. And then, what path should I use in 'buttonImage: "path"

The file (calendar.png) is currently saved in assets/images and have tried it in various other directories and various paths with no luck. The view always shows the missing image icon. I'm new to the asset pipeline.

Here is the view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Date %>:
  <%= f.text_field :requested_from, id: 'datepicker' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :requested_from, id: 'requested-from-alt' %>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({

    dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy",

    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "?????????",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select a date",

    numberOfMonths: 2,
    altField: "#requested-from-alt",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: '0',
    maxDate: '+1y',
   });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a followup, I"m also using a bootstrap theme and have access to the FontAwesome Icons. I could use the calendar icon (fa-calendar) instead of an image file, but I really have no idea how to use that in buttonImage: "xxxx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: And then, what path should I use in 'buttonImage: "path" 
Answer: '/assets/your_image.format'
example: '/assets/calendar.png'

```
dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy",
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "/assets/calendar.png",
buttonImageOnly: true,
buttonText: "Select a date",
```

Comment: Thanks, Rubyrider - I had left off the preceding / in "/assets..."